# YoloV3: Training set, true label boxes vs anchor boxes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, object-detection, yolo

I understand the anchor boxes as a set of boxes that based on a comprehensive exploration of the data ( all the true bonding boxes) best describe the variable sizes of all true boxes in the training data set. From other posts I see that the output tensor has this shape (for a binary classification): (52,52,B,s+c), (26,26,B,s+c) and (13,13,B,s+c),

where:

B= number of anchor boxes

s= 5, (o,Xc,Yc,w,h)

c= one hot encode of classes (0,1 or 1,0)

for s, knowing that:

o= If the object is present in the cell (0 or 1)

Xc= coordinate in the x axis for center of object

Yc= coordinate in the y axis for center of object

Now, for a given sample in the training set, is w,h the width and height of the true labels or the predefined anchor boxes?

Because I see that if you restring w,h to just a small set of predefined anchor boxes' w,h you might not be able to capture the full size of the real object when having many objects of different sizes..
On the other hand, if w,h are the width and height of the true labels, what is the point of using predefined anchor boxes?